# Why isn't the new values for the variable not taking affect in void update in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, void

I was trying to get an object to change direction when it hits another object but for some reason when it hits an object, the original object stands still.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class playerController : MonoBehaviour {

public float c =0;
public float a =0; 
public float d =1;
private Rigidbody rb;

void Start ()
{

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {

    a = 0;
    c = -1;
    d = 0;


}

void fixedUpdate ()
{


    transform.Translate (c*1f, a*1f, d*1f);
}
```

}

Comment: Is this a case sensitivity issue? `fixedUpdate` and `FixedUpdate` are not the same in the computer's eye.

Comment: Multiplying by 1 has shown over the years to not affect the result by a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try "FixedUpdate" instead of "fixedUpdate".

Comment: Absolutely, c# is case-sensitive